# PySpark Can't Connect to MongoDB, but Command-line Can

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark

Trying to load a MongoDB collection into a PySpark DataFrame.  First of all.. I'm able to connect using the command line on the NameNode:

```
mongo mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DB_NAME

MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://HOST/DB_NAME
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
>
```

I run the script on the cluster as follows:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--driver-memory 4g \
--executor-memory 2g \
--executor-cores 3 \
--num-executors 10 \
--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1 \
load_from_mongo.py
```

Now I create a SparkSession:

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("TestMongoLoad") \
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", 'mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:27017') \
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.database", DB_NAME) \
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection", COLLECTION_NAME) \
            .getOrCreate()
```

Then I attempt to read in the DataFame:

```
    df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
              .load()
    df.show(5, truncate=False)
```

The result is that it fails authentication.  Clearly I'm passing something incorrectly...

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/ubuntu/server/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-caedf270-dd43-42f2-a39e-e3d1b7134046;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.4.1 in central
    found org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;3.10.2 in central
    [3.10.2] org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;[3.10,3.11)
:: resolution report :: resolve 1129ms :: artifacts dl 4ms
    :: modules in use:
    org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;3.10.2 from central in [default]
    org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.4.1 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   2   |   1   |   0   |   0   ||   2   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-caedf270-dd43-42f2-a39e-e3d1b7134046
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 2 already retrieved (0kB/7ms)
20/02/29 21:26:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/load_from_mongo.py", line 124, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/load_from_mongo.py", line 102, in main
    keyword_df = getKeywordCorpus(args.begin_dt, args.end_dt)
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/load_from_mongo.py", line 79, in getKeywordCorpus
    df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o57.load.
: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='USER', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:173)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$300(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:152)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:390)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:106)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:109)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandReadOperation.execute(CommandReadOperation.java:56)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.executeCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:184)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:153)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:148)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:237)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:237)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:174)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:174)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withMongoClientDo(MongoConnector.scala:157)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withDatabaseDo(MongoConnector.scala:174)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.hasSampleAggregateOperator(MongoConnector.scala:237)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.hasSampleAggregateOperator$lzycompute(MongoRDD.scala:221)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.hasSampleAggregateOperator(MongoRDD.scala:221)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoInferSchema$.apply(MongoInferSchema.scala:68)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.constructRelation(DefaultSource.scala:97)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server HOST:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:299)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:130)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:54)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Any reason for the mongo uri with `'`?

Comment: @Lamanus I tend to use single quotes for things that don't want or need interpolation.  Left-over habit from Perl.  Gives the same errors when I use double quotes around "mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:27017".

Comment: Seems like Spark tries authenticate for `admin` database, while in command line it does for `DB_NAME`

Comment: Then try to put your DB name at the end of uri not the other option.

Comment: @Lamanus  Thank you!  It works now in standalone mode.  Still working on getting it to run on the cluster.  If you can, pls check out my other question on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as @Lamanus alluded above, was to change the URI slightly:

```
  MONGO_URL = "mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:27017/DB_NAME"

  spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('TestMongoLoad') \
            .config('spark.mongodb.input.uri', MONGO_URL) \
            .config('spark.mongodb.input.collection', COLLECTION) \
            .getOrCreate()
```